# How do I add "Dynamic-link library" and ".cs (he header file for Visual C# .NET)" in VScode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, dll, header-files

I used to use Visual Studio 2017 C# to make winform projects. The projects were to connect a FANUC CNC machine by adding the ".dll" and the header file ".cs" provided by FANUC company so that I could use its API to fetch some data I needed from the machine.

In Visual Studio, I just need to put the .dll under the path of myproject/bin/debug/ and add the header file ".cs" by right clicking the project name and "add → existing file", then I can use those API...

However, I don't know how to do with VScode. I'm a newbie and just started on it. So, it'd be ok if you could explain it in details, thank you so much!

Comment: C# doesn't have "header files". What exactly is inside this "header file" you're referring to?

Comment: Is this DLL file a native-code DLL with C-style exported functions and the "header file" is a series of `DllImport` / `extern` static functions?

Comment: I think it's a "Class", which is the library for the machine. It looks like

`using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Focas1
{
    /* Axis define */
#if FS30D
    public const short MAX_AXIS = 32;
#elif M_AXIS2
    public const short MAX_AXIS = 24;
#elif FS15D
    public const short MAX_AXIS = 10;
#else
    public const short MAX_AXIS = 8;
#endif

    public const short ALL_AXES     = (-1);
    public const short ALL_SPINDLES = (-1);
    public const short EW_OK        = (short)focas_ret.EW_OK;`

Comment: (YES~) Is this DLL file a native-code DLL with C-style exported functions and the "header file" is a series of DllImport / extern static functions?

Comment: in VS adding the dll to the project only copies the dll to the debug or release directory on build. Just make sure the dll can be found when you run the c# program.

Comment: Thank you and yes, I know that. But I'm asking about how to do it with "Visual Studio Code."

Comment: @Dai，So... do you know how to do?